# Routing Matrix with a large number of I/O

Tags: digital, multiplexer

Lets say that i would like to make a 128x128 routing matrix with an arduino uno,

Since i am unexperienced i think of using two 4051’s for 8x8 patching and because i want to persist the patch, controlling them with two quad d type flip flops, then repeat the circuit to reach 128x128 patching capibility. Then my output count would be sufficent in arduino uno.

I think this would work but sounds unelegant to me. 
Do you have another advice for me to achieve this task?

Actually what I would like to achieve is a big digitally controlled patching matrix for my own analog synth circuits at home. So analog signals will be present and should have the avalibility to patch anything to anything.

Comment: That is 128*128 = 16384 junctions! Can you tell what it is for? Is it for analog signals in both directions? Can all inputs be active at the same time? Please update you question with more information. This is the arduino section, I think your question will be moved to the electronics section.

Comment: Actually what I would like to achieve is a big digitally controlled patching matrix for my own analog synth circuits at home. So analog signals will be present and should have the avalibility to patch anything to anything.

Comment: Can you draw a circuit with two 4051's for a 8x8 matrix? They have a single common pin, they are not a matrix. The cd4066 has 4 analog switches, then you need 16384/4 = 4096 of those chips.

Comment: I think it can be done with 2304 74HC4067 chips ((1+8)*256). Who can reduce the amount of chips that are needed further?

Comment: Ah you are right, I thought terribly wrong, this way they can not be patched at the same time. Rudy’s advice for ad 75019 explains the situation. Sorry a bit confused now.

Comment: But isn’t there a way to go for this task not using amazing amount of chips?

Comment: I think that there is not a single chip for 128x128. A small module for 8x8 or 16x16 can not easily be scaled up, because it is a two-dimensional matrix. You need a large amount of chips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a port expander that uses I2C for communications. One example is the PCA9555. You can add up to eight by setting the address bits (A0-A2). This will give you up to 64 outputs to control the selection bits of the 4051s.

[image]

While this is all intelectionally possible, from a logic perspective, I have concerns about how this can be practically implemented. I think you need to go into more detail on what you plan to do. What the purpose is.

Also, there are larger chip for do analog matrix switching. AD75019 is one example. https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad75019.html

They are more expensive but cost should not be the primary factor. Getting a design to work is more important.

Do a search for "Crosspoint Switch Array" for more chips like this.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you i will immediately chack all of those. What are your concerns about practical implementation?

Comment: Anything that large is a problem. Physical implementation. Noise issues.  What is your application?

Comment: I edited the question to include my purpose.

Comment: OK that's more doable. I was worried you were trying to take signals in from the real world. Good luck.

Comment: 20 dollars per ad75019. How many will be needed?

Comment: Well, since this is the case I can live with 6 of them. Maybe 96x96 is big enough.

Comment: Six ad75019 make a matrix of 16x96. I think you need 36.

Comment: Ah you are right, but these were quite informational for me thank you both. Now I get the picture better I would research according to that. Well maybe in the future this would not be a bad investment for such a large patch bay. Do you think there will be other problems that i can not think of right now in such a large project? Like rudy mensioned, distortion, noise?

Comment: Anything that complex will be difficult. It will certainly be a learning experience. (problems that need to be solved) I suggest starting small. Also look to see how other people have done something similar.

Comment: This one is 100$ and I think can keep me busy for a long time, thanks again.
32x32 Analog Switch Matrix,ADV3200.
 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADV3200_ADV3201.pdf

Comment: Of course you would need to make a custom circuit board. 0.5mm pitch is hard to solder. I hate fine pitched components. I do some, but I tend to leave most of it to the production department at work.